# Problem with finding "x" in triangle

Tags: problem-solving, triangles, rectangles

I have got a problem with finding the x. I think the question isn't true or there should more informations on it.
[image: find the x]

Comment: I have provided a solution path, but without any hint of what you have tried I will not be able to know what your level is. Please post some indication of what you have tried and what has failed.

Comment: In your picture it looks like AE=DE and that is certainly not true though

Comment: I dont know AE=DE or not @imranfat

Comment: @JeremyUpsal I could not find any solution. Please start from low level

Comment: Look at your answers to this question. There are two clear answers. Try them and ask if you get confused.

Comment: For future reference, even if you haven't managed to find a solution, it is desirable that you tell us what you've tried and what your thoughts are about the problem. This will help us to better tailor our answers/hints to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly enough information. Note that in this answer I will use $\overline{AB}$ to denote the line from $A$ to $B$. Note that you have a 30-60-90 triangle (ABE) which allows you to find ($\overline{BE}$) (you can derive this using trigonometry if you know it, or take a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/30-60-90Triangle.html). Then, you can also find ($\overline{AE}$) to be

$d=\overline{AE} = \frac{2a}{\sqrt{3}}$

and subsequently ($\overline{ED}$),

$\overline{ED} = \overline{AD}-d$

which gives you one side in a 30-60-90 triangle, allowing you to find ($\overline{EF}$). Now you have two sides and an angle in a triangle, you can easily find $X$ using trigonometry from there!

Answer (score 0):

With coordinates, if $B=(0,0)$, $A=(1,0)$, $D=(1,1)$, $C=(0,1)$, we find that
$$E=(1,\frac 1{\sqrt 3})$$ and then $$F=(1-\sqrt3\cdot(1-\frac1{\sqrt 3}),1)=(2-\sqrt 3,1)$$
so that 
$$ \tan\angle FBC = \sqrt 3-1$$
and finally 
$$ x = 60^\circ -\arctan(\sqrt 3-1)$$